# Get the value of the field

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

There is a class

```
class Real {

    static constraints = {
        param_name()
        param_descr()
        param_type(inList: ["val",
                        "symbol",
                        "string",
                        "Boolean",
        ])
    }

    String param_name
    String param_descr
    String param_type
}
```

Can I get ***param_type*** values?

If so, how?

I need my *isList* values for further work

Well, or can it somehow be done differently?

Comment: I think you can use Enum for that. http://grails.asia/groovy-enum-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in grails 3 you would access this value list like this:

```
Real.getConstrainedProperties().param_type.inList
```

in grails 2 this was just

```
Real.constraints.param_type.inList
```

This will return the list of values that you could use in a `<g:select>` for instance

```
<g:select id="theType" from="${Real.getConstrainedProperties().param_type.inList}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Friend, I think you misunderstood about the constraints in grails or groovy.

"Constraints provide Grails with a declarative DSL for defining validation rules, schema generation and CRUD generation meta data". 
For example, consider these constraints:

class User {
    ...

```
static constraints = {
    login size: 5..15, blank: false, unique: true
    password size: 5..15, blank: false
    email email: true, blank: false
    age min: 18
}
```

}

the use of inlist is:
Validates that a value is within a range or collection of constrained values.
For ex: name(inList: ["Joe", "Fred", "Bob"])

In your scenario, you validate that a param_type value within a collection of constrained values which you given in inList.

For more information, please refer following grails offical page
https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html

If i misunderstood about your question pls comment me.